# One Angular page with many url:s

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple Angular app (for training purpose since I am a Angular-rookie :)) with a ul-list containing some books. If the user clicks on a book a detail view will appear below the list with some details about that book. I want that if the user clicks on the book the url should change to something like /#/[book-id]. The user should also of course be able to browse directly to this url where the details view for the specific book is visible. I have not figure out how to do this with routes. I paste my sample code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="libraryApp">
        <div id="list" ng-controller="listCtrl">
            <ul ng-repeat="book in data.list">
                <li><a href="" ng-click="openDetailView(book)">{{ book.name }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="detailView" ng-controller="detailCtrl">
            <div  ng-if="data.currentBook" style="background-color: #EEE; padding: 10px 0;">
                <h1>{{ data.currentBook.name }}</h1>
                <div>Number of pages: {{ data.currentBook.pages }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    angular.module("libraryApp", [])

     .factory("dataFactory", function() {
        return {
            list: [
                    { id: 1, name: "The Great Gatsy", pages: 423 },
                    { id: 2, name: "1984", pages: 332 },
                    { id: 3, name: "The Lord Of The Rings", pages: 632 }
                ],
            currentBook: null
        };
     })

    .controller("listCtrl", function($scope, dataFactory) {
        $scope.data = dataFactory;
        $scope.openDetailView = function(book) {
            $scope.data.currentBook = book;
        };
    })

    .controller("detailCtrl", function($scope, dataFactory) {
        $scope.data = dataFactory;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put this code in your code ...

angular.module("libraryApp", ['ngRought'])

```
.config(function ($routeProvider)
```

{

$routeProvider

```
.when("/bookname",
{
        templateUrl: "path of the html file",
        controller: "listCtrl"
    })
.when("/date",
{
        templateUrl: "path of the html file",
        controller: "detailCtrl"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda difficult to answer since there are so many ways to do this, but look into https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

You'll use your module's `config` block to set up the routing with `$stateProvider`, then specify the controllers and templates you'd like to use when a user changes the application's state.  This means you'll probably need to move those divs for your different views to separate files (or something creative to get their content -- getting the element's html with `jQuery` or something would work).

I'm not going into many details because this is something that can be answered easily now that you know to use ui-router :)

Answer (score 0):

It's called nested view. To use it you'd be better try ui-router: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1/item/b